# UIWebView "document.height" evaluation returns wrong height on older iphones (specifically 4s and 5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

The problem is that, i have a tableview with several cells, and have a  webView in one of these cells. By disabling the scroll on the webview, i should have a static web content view scrolling in the tableView, not by itself, which all works great.
In the webViewDidFinishLoad method i call

`[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.height"] floatValue];`

then set this value in heightForRowAtIndexPath by reloading the table. It all works great on iPhone 6 and up, but on 4s and 5, the bottom of my web content is clipped off. The returned height difference is completely random, with 724 pixel height being unclipped and fine, on other content with nearly the same returned pixel height cut off by more than 30% percent of the original.

I tried several approaches that i found here, but none of them worked.
Tried to get the max value from evaluating the offsetheight, scrollheight and other properties, but also without success.
Also tried running jquery commands on my webview, but again, without success so far.
If anyone has any experience with a problem like this, please help.
The full code snippet, where "articleViewHeight" is a constraint for the mentioned webView:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [self getCellHeight:indexPath.row];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self getCellHeight:indexPath.row];
}

-(CGFloat)getCellHeight:(NSInteger)row{
switch (row) {
    case 0:
        return self.view.frame.size.height * 0.1f;
        break;
    case 1:
        return self.view.frame.size.height * 0.375f;
        break;
    case 2:
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;//self.view.frame.size.height * 0.15f;
        break;
    case 3:
        return self.articleViewHeight;
        break;
    case 4:
        return self.view.frame.size.height * 0.2f;
        break;
    default:
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        break;
    }
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView * _Nonnull)webView{

    CGFloat height = [self getWebViewPageHeight];

    self.articleViewHeight = height;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self removeLoader];
}

- (CGFloat) getWebViewPageHeight {
    CGFloat height1 = [[self.articleView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.height"] floatValue];
    CGFloat height2 = [[self.articleView  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.scrollHeight"] floatValue];

return MAX(height1, height2);
}
```

Update: the htmlstring loading code as requested

```
-(void)doneLoading{
   NSString *pathToFile =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"news" ofType:@"css"];
   NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   NSString* headerString = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head title='test'><style type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\">%@</style></head><body><div id='content'>%@</div></body></html>";

   NSString * theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:headerString,fileString,self.htmlString];
   [self.articleView loadHTMLString:theString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: A more extensive code snippet would be useful to help users understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: Is the thing you're loading into a webview local html content or actual, online page?

Comment: Its local, an HTML string.

Comment: Great, please add this info to your question, and I'll write an answer.

Comment: Please, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution works only for local html string which you can freely modify (well, you could download webpage separately into a string and inject this but then you get a load of other problems.**

I've had similar problem and found following method to solve them. First of all, add this script in the `<head>` tag of your html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        window.location.href = "height://"+document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
    }
</script>
```

This is needed because when `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;` is called the content still may not have correct height. Also, put all your html content into one div with id from the script ("content" int this example).

```
... html header
<body>
    <div id="content">
        ... your content
    </div>
</body>
```

Then modify your `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;` method.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)pWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)pRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)pNavigationType{
    NSURL* url = pRequest.URL;
    if(pNavigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){
        return ![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        // or do whatever you do with normal links
    } else if([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"height"]){
        CGFloat contentHeight = [url.host floatValue];
        // do your thing with height
    }
}
```

And viola! This made it for me. Any height error was so marginal that adding small (2px) additional bottom padding for content in CSS completely shown my content.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed important thing in my code. The webview have `.scaleToPage` flag set to `NO` and even more important: initial height of webview. It's set to 6k. If I change it to 0, sure enought, the content is cut after loading.

**So to get correct height, the initial height of wevbiew during loading must be big enough to store whole html content without scrolling.**

Since you have your webview in a cell, this won't help you. So maybe put another, hidden and big webview on the bottom of drawing stack, with same width as the one in the cell and load your conent there first, get height and then load the one in a cell.

Comment: Well, didn't work for me, this returns the same value as
"document.body.offsetheight" from my "getWebViewPageHeight", which i already removed, because it was always smaller than document.height...

Answer (score -1):

I have had a requirement to have `web view` in `scrollview`.

The way I handled, tested without any hack. Actually this delegate method is called multiple times in a single request. Your `webViewDidFinishLoad` must be like below:

There is a delegate `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`

I calculate web view height:-

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
if (webView.isLoading == NO)// as it is called multiple times so wait untill last call
            {
                NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"webView": webView};
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:WEB_VIEW_FINISH_LOAD object:nil userInfo:userInfo];//sending to compute content size for any view which is using this class
            }
            [self hideActivityOverlayAnimation:NO];
    }
```

This is how i have computed web view height:

```
-(void)webViewFinishedLoad:(NSNotification*)notification{

if ([notification.name isEqualToString:WEB_VIEW_FINISH_LOAD])
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    UIWebView* webView = (UIWebView*)userInfo[@"webView"];

    [webView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];// it was my requirement, dont have to do any thing with height calculation
    CGFloat **height** = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];//every time it returnes different

}

}
```

You can use this height to resize your cell height.

The main part which puzzle me was above. My set Up method of web view:

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webViewFrame];
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Hope it will help you !!!

Comment: Sadly, this was not the solution, on my part the didfinishload only called once, and the .isLoading is <nil>

Comment: can you show more code how you are loading local string in web view

Comment: While i appreciate the effort, posting the allocation of the webview object won't help at all.

Comment: it was more of the content mode, delegate and scaling :)

Comment: Yeah i understand. I didn't write about it, but im way past these small things, tried changing content modes, tried scaletofit, but none of them makes any difference.

Comment: why down vote any reason for that ! have given description of code , proper formatted !! can you please provide me feed back so that i can make it correct that time